# Performing a JOIN in LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing some C# that has some entities. My entities are:

```
Address        Store
-------        -----
ID             ID
StreetAddress  AddressID
City           Name
State
```

I need to do a LINQ query that gives  me all of the stores for a certain city. Currently, I have:

```
var addresses = await Address.GetFromDatabase();
var results = address in addresses
              where (address.City == 'Seattle')
              select new
              {
                StoreID = store.ID
                StoreAddress = address.StreetAddress
              }
```

This code obviously does not work. The join to Store does not exist. However, because `Store` must also hit the database, I'm not sure what to do. I appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: is this just linq to entities?

Comment: Can't use navigation properties? `Var res=db.Stores.Where(s=>s.Address.City=="Seatle")`

Comment: Besides all you should iterate stores instead of addresses (some addresses may not match any store.Id)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do joins in LINQ and it's pretty straightforward:

```
var results = from address in addresses
              join store in stores
              on address.ID equals store.AddressID
              where (address.City == 'Seattle')
              select store;
```

Comment: I'd be careful, if this is linq to entities, you may want to ToList is to avoid the multi queries you could run using IEnumerable